# Correct way to merge two serialized querysets on common foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say I have (as a contrived example) two models `Dog` and `House`, who have foreign keys for their owner. For this example assume that each `Owner` can have a maximum of one `Dog` and one `House`.

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    fk_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)

class House(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6) #hexcode
    fk_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
```

I get the serialized data from the API. I can get it separately for the `Dog` and `House` objects like so:

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from my_app import Dog

class DogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.CharField(source=fk_owner.name, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ('name', 'owner')
        #same thing for House
```

dog_api.py

```
from my_app.views import DogSerializer
from my_app.models import Dog
from rest_framework import generics
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@method_decorator(api_view(['GET']), name='dispatch')
class DogAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    model=Dog
    serializer_class=DogSerializer
    queryset = Dog.objects.all()
```

Which will give me JSON: `[{"name" : "SnoopDogg", "owner" : "Bob Jones"}, etc]`

#### The question:

What's the best practice way to combine two JSON queries that have the same `Owner` (remembering that each `Owner` only owns one `House` and `Dog`)? Can DRF do it, or do I need to write my own merge function? I want to generate this JSON:

```
[{"name":"SnoopDogg", "owner":"Bob Jones", "house":
    {"address":"1 Main St", "color":"FC09A9"}
},
{"name":"Snoopy", "owner":"Charlie Brown", "house":
    {"address":"1 Comic Strip", "color":"00FF00"}
},
etc...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if an owner can only have one dog and one house, then you should use a [`OneToOne` relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) instead of OneToMany.

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    fk_owner = models.OneToOneField(Owner)

class House(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6) #hexcode
    fk_owner = models.OneToOneField(Owner)
```

If I get you right, you want the `DogAPI` view also to return the house where the owner/dog lives. You can do that by defining a `HouseSerializer`  and and a `SerializerMethodField` in the `DogSerializer`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from my_app import Dog, House

class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = House

class DogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.CharField(source=fk_owner.name, read_only=True)
    house = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ('name', 'owner', 'house')

    def get_house(self, obj):
        """
        Return serialized house data
        """
        house = obj.fk_owner.house
        return HouseSerializer(house).data
```